# Conflicting / Multiple start commands between `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was following [this tutorial](https://rubyinrails.com/2019/03/29/dockerify-rails-6-application-setup/) to get a Rails 6 Application up and running on Docker (although this question isn't specific to Rails)

In the `Dockerfile` it has the following command

```
# The main command to run when the container starts. Also
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by
# default.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Great, so it's giving it a startup command to start the rails server locally.

Later in the same article it shows the following in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  ...

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "foreman start -f Procfile.dev-server"
    ...
```

Now it's providing a *different* command to start the app (using the `foreman` gem, which likely starts the rails server in a similar fashion to the first command).

Which "command" is the one that actually executes and starts everything up? Does the docker-compose command override the `Dockerfile` `CMD` when I run `docker-compose up` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `command:` in `docker-compose.yml`, or the command given at the end of a `docker run` command, takes precedence.  No matter what else you specify, a container only runs *one* command, and then exits.

In a typical image that does package some single application, best practice is to `COPY` the application code (or compiled binary) in and set an appropriate `CMD` that runs it, even if in development you'll be running it with modified settings.